# React Typescript project .map function working only one time after compilation

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to create a frontend for my app using React and TypeScript.
I am gathering data from my backend (simple DRF app) and fetching it using Axios and pushing it into separate arrays.

```ts
const myApi = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
})

let idArr:number [] = new Array()
let titleArr:string [] = new Array()
let contentArr:string [] = new Array()


myApi.get('/getallarticles').then( res => {
    for(let elem in res.data)
    {
        idArr.push(res.data[elem].id)
        titleArr.push(res.data[elem].title)
        contentArr.push(res.data[elem].content)
    }
})
```

The app contains a page named feed into which I parse the id Array.

```jsx
function App() {
    console.log(idArr)
    return (
      <Box>
        <Navbar/>
          <Grid alignItems={"center"} justifyContent={"center"} marginLeft={'15%'} marginRight={'15%'}>
              <Stack  spacing={2} margin={2}>
                  <Box id='res_viewer'>
                      <Feed content={"CONTENT FROM MAIN"} id={10} title={"Sherlock Holmes"} total={5} idArr={idArr}/>
                  </Box>
              </Stack>
          </Grid>
      </Box>
  );
}
```

Then in my page Feed I copy the ActionCard (from Mui5) and the problem is that all the Cards show only if I recompile the project. It only works one time, and I have no idea why. Moreover if I put the console.log and alert into the Feed the console.log would show an array every time, while Alert only the first time. Anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

```tsx
const Feed = ({ id, title, content, total, idArr }: { id: number; title: string; content: string; total: number; idArr:Array<number>}) => {
    console.log(idArr)
    alert(idArr)
    return(
        <div>
            {idArr.map(customId =>
                <Card key={customId} variant="outlined" sx={{ margin: 0 }}>
                    <CardActionArea>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                                {customId}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                                {content}
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                    </CardActionArea>
                    <CardActions>
                        <Button style={{
                            color: "#ff0000",
                        }} size="large" startIcon={<DeleteForever />}>
                            DELETE
                        </Button>
                        <Button style={{
                            color: "#68ee06",
                        }} size="large" startIcon={<Edit />}>
                            EDIT
                        </Button>
                    </CardActions>
                </Card>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Feed
```

[image]

Comment: It only works the first time you do what exactly? Are you saying it works when you restart a react dev server or when you do a production build? And are you saying that the cards don't show up on browser refresh? A list of steps and observations at each step would be helpful.

Comment: It only works the first time I add anything to a project. It could be just a new line, so that the project recompiles. Essentially. I add anything, the react restarts the server and the app works, including alert. If I refresh the page there is no content on it, console. log shows ok array, but  alert shows empty window.

Comment: After further inspection I found, that it is a problem with getting all the data from server. For some reason the first time the app gets response from server the app can ex. display length of the array. The next time we refresh the page it cannot, however the array is still populated. Weird.

Comment: I posted an answer, let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the asynchronous nature of the call to your API is what's giving this behavior. When making calls to an API for data, it's common to use a `useEffect` hook that updates a `state`. This ensures that the UI is in sync with the data. Try rewriting as follows:

```
const myApi = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
})

const [idArr, setIdArr] = useState([] as number[]);
const [titleArr, setTitleArr] = useState([] as string[]);
const [contentArr, setContentArr] = useState([] as string[]);

useEffect(() => {
  myApi.get('/getallarticles').then(res => {
    const newIds: number[] = [];
    const newTitles: string[] = [];
    const newContents: string[] = [];

    for (let elem in res.data) {
      newIds.push(res.data[elem].id);
      newTitles.push(res.data[elem].title);
      newContents.push(res.data[elem].content);
    }

    setIdArr(newIds);
    setTitleArr(newTitles);
    setContentArr(newContents);
  });
}, []);
```